# Nav bar is added on top off already existing nav bar after programatic push

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8

When I programmatically push from a view controller to the tab bar controller it adds a nav bar on top of the already existing nav bar. Within the tab bar controller I have three view controllers that have been embedded with nav controllers. Now my question is how can I programmatically push to tab bar controller showing just the existing nav bar? Its works perfectly when I programmatically present to the tab bar controller but I want to programmatically  push to the tab bar controller. below is the code I am using to push to tab bar

```
let tabBarController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbarController") as? UITabBarController

        let nav = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
        let guestVC = nav.topViewController as! guestProfileViewController

        let nav1 = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as! UINavigationController
        let guestVC1 = nav1.topViewController as! newGuestPhotoViewController

        let nav2 = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[2] as! UINavigationController
        let guestVC2 = nav2.topViewController as! newGuestVideoViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarController!, animated: true)
```

As you can see from the photo below it shows 2 nav bars.
[image]

But I want to show just the existing nav bar as shown below. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You are in a Nav Controller... you push to a TabBarController, so the NavBar will be there, allowing you to "pop" back. But - based on the little code you posted - each Tab contains a NavigationController, which will have its own NavBar (so you can push/pop navigate to additional VCs within that tab. Do you *not* want to allow the user to navigate **back** from the TabBarController (to whatever screen you pushed from)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DonMag. I do want the user to be able to navigate back but from the navigationController within the tabs. Is that possible?

Comment: When I programmatically present the tab controller it works perfectly and I'm able to navigate back from any tab however I want to push to the tab controller because I want the tab controller to slide when dismissed as oppose to tab controller dropping down when dismissed @DonMag

Comment: OK - you'll have a little trouble with that approach. You *could* hide the main NavBar when you push to the TabController, but the transition would look odd. One way to do what you want is to *present* the tab controller with a custom "slide-in" transition, and then manually add a "Back" button on the NavBars of the Tab's controllers... which would trigger a *dismiss* with a custom "slide-out" transition. Odd UX though, as the user would push-push-pop-pop on the NavControllers within the tabs, and then suddenly it would "pop" away from the TabController

Comment: ok thanks @DonMag for the help. I will give it a try